# Proper Scala syntax to turn higher-order function into anonymous function?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, anonymous-function, higher-order-functions

I would like to eliminate the `inverse` function in the example below and just create an anonymous function directly in the call to `bar`. Can anyone suggest the correct syntax? I've tried a few variations but can't get anything to compile.

```
object Test {

  def foo(p: Int => Boolean): Boolean = {
    def inverse(p: Int => Boolean): Int => Boolean = {
      e: Int => !p(e)
    }

    bar(inverse(p))
  }

  def bar(p: Int => Boolean): Boolean = true

}
```

Comment: I don't know scala, but what about `bar((e:Int) => !p(e))`? Edit: err, didn't read the code good enough

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should work

```
bar(!p(_))
```

stackoverflow says this answer is too short.